# win7 unable to join openldap domain: LDAPMessage searchRequest(4) "<ROOT>" baseObject

Tags: openldap

my Win7 machine is unable to join my linux openldap domain. In wireshark I can see that win7 machine sends CLDAP search message to openldap with the following parameter:

 LDAPMessage searchRequest(4) "ROOT>" baseObject

 protocolOp: searchRequest (3)
 searchRequest
 baseObject:
 Filter: (&(&(DnsDomain=mydomain.com)(Host=ZAK))(NtVer=0x00000016))
 .....................................

 AttributeDescription: Netlogon
 

However, in my LDAP entries none of the search attributes (DnsDomain, HOST,NtVer) exist. Any advice is very welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: hmmm...I added binddn and bindpw to the nslcd.conf an now in wireskark I can see that windows machine is sending this request to my linux samba/ldap domain : " NBNS 94 Name query NB ZAK"   and the linux machine is answering by: "NBNS Name query response, Requested name does not exist unknown" . Maybe something is wrong with my samba configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by uninstalling openldap and samba3 and installing samba4. Samba4 plays the role of ldap and active directory. Windows machines are now able to join the linux domain.